Optimal game order for God Gamer challenge?
The challenge (if I'm not mistaken) is to play 10 different multiplayer games and win in all of them back to back. If you ever lose any of them, you need to start from the beginning. The question is: what is the optimal order to play the games in to minimize the expected time to complete the challenge? Should you save the harder/longer games for last? Or get them out of the way first?
To formalize, there are $n$ games you need to win back to back. Game $i$ takes $t_i$ seconds on average to complete, and will result in a win with probability $p_i$. What ordering $\pi\in \text{Perm}\left(\{1,\ldots, n\}\right)$ will result in the lowest average completion time?
If possible, I'd also like some idea heuristically on how to make the choice.
What I've worked out is that, if you play the games in order from $i=1$ to $i=n$, the average time $T$ to complete the challenge will be
$$T = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \left(t_i\cdot\left(\Pi_{j=1}^{i-1}p_i\right)\right)}{\Pi_{i=1}^n p_i} = \frac{t_1 + p_1 t_2 + p_1 p_2 t_3 + \cdots}{p_1\cdot\cdots\cdot p_n}$$
This can be found relatively simply by writing the recurrence relation for what $T$ is. The denominator isn't affected by order, which leaves optimizing the numerator with respect to the ordering of the games. But I'm not sure how to go about doing it simply.
What I can say is, in the case of $n=2$, then the math says that the game that you should play first is the one where $\frac{t_i}{q_i}$ is lowest (where $q_i = 1-p_i$ is the loss rate). So shorter games where you lose more often should be prioritized. I'm not sure how nicely this generalizes beyond $n=2$ though....
Just an interesting problem I encountered that I thought I'd share and ask about here.
Inspired by CDawgVA and Ludwig having recently completed the challenge apparently (took them 96 hours @.@).

From numerical testing, it seems that my rule for $n=2$ is optimal for $n=3$ and beyond. Haven't proved it rigorously though.

It will not change the conclusion, but why do you divide the average time by $p_1...p_n$?

A way to prove your conjecture is to show that you cannot have tasks $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$ with $\frac{t_i}{q_i} > \frac{t_{i+1}}{q_{i+1}}$ (by showing it is more efficient to permute these). By factoring the other probabilities, you get back to the $n=2$ case.

Show that swapping the order of two consecutive games $i$ and $j$ will decrease the average completion time if and only if $\frac{t_i}{q_i}>\frac{t_j}{q_j}$. So the shortest average completion time is when no such swaps are possible, i.e. when the games are ordered with respect to increasing $\frac tq$.
